# I don't understand this notation- abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

May be a stupid question but is $(\mathbb{Z}^n)_p \equiv \mathbb{Z}^n/(\mathbb{Z}p)^n$ (when $p$ is a prime)??

Comment: Where did you find this? A book? It must have the definition there. Probably is what you write...but not sure,

Comment: Does $\mathbb{Z}p$ mean $p\mathbb{Z} = \{ pn : n \in\mathbb{Z}\}$?

Comment: It's in a home assignment... I don't know where did my instructor found it...

Comment: @Braindead Indeed, that's what I meant

Comment: Well, the right side is well-defined. I guess it boils down to what $(\mathbb{Z}^n)_p$ means. Is it suppose to be $(\mathbb{Z}_p)^n$?

Comment: Are you sure it's $(\mathbb Z^n)_p$ and not $(\mathbb Z_p)^n$, which is usually written as $\mathbb Z_p^n$?

Comment: Yes I am, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Without more context it's hard to know for sure, but this looks like a definition for $\left(\Bbb Z^n\right)_p$.  It's being defined as the Cartesian product

$$\underbrace{\Bbb Z\times\dots\times\Bbb Z}_{n\,\mathrm{times}}$$

modulo the Cartesian product

$$\underbrace{p\Bbb Z\times\dots\times p\Bbb Z}_{n\,\mathrm{times}}\,.$$